# Tracking z3::optimize unsat_core

Tags: c++, z3

How to properly track `z3::optimize` unsat core?

The Z3 C++ `z3::optimize` does not find the expected solution when I add *unsat_core* tracking (based on these [examples](https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3/blob/9df6c10ad87ae37c7deba1e7428496dbd5ab0022/examples/c%2B%2B/example.cpp#L395)) (gcc 10.1.0).

Take the following problem: There are three consecutive points `A`, `B`, and `C`, where `A` and `C` are fixed to 0 and 200, respectively. Determine `B`'s position such that `B - A >= 10`, `C - B >= 15`, and our optimization goal is `minimize(C - B)`. The solution for this problem should be `B = C - 15 = 200 - 15 = 185`.

The **untracked code below** gives the correct solution.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <z3++.h>

int main()
{
  z3::context ctx;
  z3::optimize opt(ctx);

  opt.add(ctx.int_const("A") == 0);
  opt.add(ctx.int_const("B") - ctx.int_const("A") >= 10);
  opt.add(ctx.int_const("C") - ctx.int_const("B") >= 15);
  opt.add(ctx.int_const("C") == 200);

  auto h = opt.minimize(ctx.int_const("C") - ctx.int_const("B"));

  if (opt.check() != z3::sat)
    std::cout << "unsat problem!\n" << opt.unsat_core() << std::endl;
  else
    std::cout << "model!\n" << opt.get_model() << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

On the other hand, **tracking the unsat_core with** `void add(expr const& e, expr const& t)` return `B=10`, which is not the expect solution. Nonetheless, I am able to track the unsat core if need - e.g. adding `opt.add(ctx.int_const("B") == 200, ctx.bool_const("t4"));` creates an unsat. problem.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <z3++.h>

int main()
{
  z3::context ctx;
  z3::optimize opt(ctx);

  opt.add(ctx.int_const("A") == 0, ctx.bool_const("t0"));
  opt.add(ctx.int_const("B") - ctx.int_const("A") >= 10, ctx.bool_const("t1"));
  opt.add(ctx.int_const("C") - ctx.int_const("B") >= 15, ctx.bool_const("t2"));
  opt.add(ctx.int_const("C") == 200, ctx.bool_const("t3"));

  auto h = opt.minimize(ctx.int_const("C") - ctx.int_const("B"));

  if (opt.check() != z3::sat)
    std::cout << "unsat problem!\n" << opt.unsat_core() << std::endl;
  else
    std::cout << "model!\n" << opt.get_model() << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Using `z3::implies` to track expressions does not work as expected either, but still provides *unsat_core* tracking capability.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <z3++.h>

int main()
{
  z3::context ctx;
  z3::optimize opt(ctx);

  opt.add(z3::implies(ctx.bool_const("t0"), ctx.int_const("A") == 0));
  opt.add(z3::implies(ctx.bool_const("t1"), ctx.int_const("B") - ctx.int_const("A") >= 10));
  opt.add(z3::implies(ctx.bool_const("t2"), ctx.int_const("C") - ctx.int_const("B") >= 15));
  opt.add(z3::implies(ctx.bool_const("t3"), ctx.int_const("C") == 200));

  auto h = opt.minimize(ctx.int_const("C") - ctx.int_const("B"));

  z3::expr_vector asv(ctx);
  asv.push_back(ctx.bool_const("t0"));
  asv.push_back(ctx.bool_const("t1"));
  asv.push_back(ctx.bool_const("t2"));
  asv.push_back(ctx.bool_const("t3"));

  if (opt.check(asv) != z3::sat)
    std::cout << "unsat problem!\n" << opt.unsat_core() << std::endl;
  else
    std::cout << "model!\n" << opt.get_model() << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Interestingly, adding a *weight* - i.e. `handle add(expr const& e, unsigned weight)` - to the expressions above - e.g. `opt.add(z3::implies(ctx.bool_const("t0"), ctx.int_const("A") == 0), 1);`, "forces" the optimizer to reach the correct solution.

What am I missing here?

**EDIT:** Curiously, if I add tracking variables `t[0-4]` to the optimizer - i.e. `opt.add(ctx.bool_const("t0"));` and so on, the optimizer finds the correct solution, but it loses the capability of tracking the unsat core expressions. That seems to make sense, considering I am changing the expression's purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

z3 doesn't support unsat-cores in the optimization mode.

See this thread for a detailed discussion of this issue: https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3/issues/1577

The recommended solution (in pseudo-code) is:

```
1.  Assert all constraints except optimization objectives
2.  Issue `check-sat`
        2.1 If `unsat`, get the unsat-core: done
        2.2 If `sat`:
              2.2.1 Assert the optimization objectives
              2.2.2 Issue `check-sat` again
              2.2.3 Get objective values
```

Admittedly, this isn't ideal; but that's the current state of the implementation. If this feature is important to you, I recommend filing a ticket with z3 as a feature-request, though without a convincing use case it's unlikely to be implemented. A better option for you might be to use parallelization capabilities in your host language: Start two threads, one with regular `sat` call, and one with `optimization`. If you get `unsat`, kill the second and get the unsat-core from the first. If you get `sat`, you can now use the results of your second call. If you have multiple cores at your disposal (who doesn't these days?) this should be almost transparent to the end-user.

Comment: And what do you make of the described behavior in which, depending on how expressions are defined, either we find the optimal solution or the unsat core *works*? Shouldn't we have an error message somewhere?

Comment: You can file an issue and ask at the z3 issue tracker. But my take is that since unsat-cores are not supported, the output you're getting is just bogus. Indeed, it would be nice if z3 issued a better error message/warning. Maybe it does do that in the SMTLib interface, but not in the C-bindings. I'd try the SMTLib interface first to see if you get a nicer error there.